# Python os.path.commonprefix - is there a path oriented function?

Tags: python, path

So I have this python code:

```
print os.path.commonprefix([r'C:\root\dir',r'C:\root\dir1'])
```

#### Real Result

```
C:\root\dir
```

#### Desired result

```
C:\root
```

#### Question 1

Based on `os.path.commonprefix` documentation:
*Return the longest path prefix (taken character-by-character)*

Is there a similar function that:
*Return the longest path prefix (**taken dir by dir**)*

#### Question 2

if `commonprefix` is implemented in `os.path` why isn't it path oriented, meaning return my desired result and not the real one?

#### Note:

I can implement this easily by myself but if it is already implemented why not using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there a path oriented function?

no and yes. `commonprefix()` can work with arbitrary sequences, not just strings.

---

Split the path into components and call `commonprefix()` on that e.g.:

```
>>> import os
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
>>> a, b = map(PureWindowsPath, [r'C:\root\dir', r'C:\root\dir1'])
>>> PureWindowsPath(*os.path.commonprefix([a.parts, b.parts]))
PureWindowsPath('C:/root')
```

Comment: Without the additional library: os.path.commonprefix([dirname.split(os.sep) for dirname in [r'C:\root\dir', r'C:\root\dir']])

Comment: @user3856011: `pathlib` is in stdlib  since Python 3.4 (you can install it on older versions including Python 2). `split(os.sep)` fails in many cases e.g., it won't work on my (posix) machine while the  code in the answer works.

Comment: Okay, your right, but in this case it works and idanshmu is using Python 2 (print statement)

Comment: @user3856011: your solution **does not** work in this case on my machine as I've already said.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't read your answer carefully. If I replace os.sep with "\\" (i use posix as well), it w

Comment: Very nice! Unfortunately, `os.path.commonprefix` is typed as if this should be impossible :( see https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/5009

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.5, you can use [`os.path.commonpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), which does exactly what you want. Unlike `commonprefix`, it works dir-by-dir.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `pathlib` only:

```py
def common_path(path1: Path, path2: Path) -> typing.Optional[Path]:
    while path1 is not None:
        if path2.is_relative_to(path1):
            return path1
        path1 = path1.parent if path1 != path1.parent else None
    return None
```