# Using pathlib's relative_to for directories on the same level

Tags: python, pathlib

The python library [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) provides [`Path.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to). This function works fine if one path is a subpath of the other one, like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
foo = Path("C:\\foo")
bar = Path("C:\\foo\\bar")
bar.relative_to(foo)

> WindowsPath('bar')
```

However, if two paths are on the *same level*, `relative_to` does not work.

```
baz = Path("C:\\baz")
foo.relative_to(baz)

> ValueError: 'C:\\foo' does not start with 'C:\\baz'
```

I would expect the result to be

```
WindowsPath("..\\baz")
```

The function [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) does this correctly:

```
import os
foo = "C:\\foo"
bar = "C:\\bar"
os.path.relpath(foo, bar)

> '..\\foo'
```

Is there a way to achieve the functionality of `os.path.relpath` using `pathlib.Path`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have run into the same problem. I would like to standardize on using pathlib over os.path whenever I can, but this problem has me stumped.

Comment: @Phil it appears in this case you're forced to get back to `os.path.relpath` :( ... It seems the `pathlib` module was not thought of as a replacement of `os.path` :(. Or have you found a `pathlib`-only solution?

Comment: No, I have not found a ``pathlib``-only solution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The first section solves the OP's problem, though if like me, he really wanted the solution relative to a common root then the second section solves it for him. The third section describes how I originally approached it and is kept for interest sake.

### Relative Paths

Recently, as in Python 3.4-6, the `os.path` module has been extended to accept `pathlib.Path` objects. In the following case however it does not return a Path object and one is forced to wrap the result.

```
foo = Path("C:\\foo")
baz = Path("C:\\baz")
Path(os.path.relpath(foo, baz))

> Path("..\\foo")
```

### Common Path

My suspicion is that you're really looking a path relative to a common root. If that is the case the following, from [EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7288019), is more useful

```
Path(os.path.commonpath([foo, baz]))

> Path('c:/root')
```

### Common Prefix

Before I'd struck upon `os.path.commonpath` I'd used `os.path.comonprefix`.

```
foo = Path("C:\\foo")
baz = Path("C:\\baz")
baz.relative_to(os.path.commonprefix([baz,foo]))

> Path('baz')
```

But be forewarned you are not supposed to use it in this context (See [commonprefix : Yes, that old chestnut](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-ideas/153nyg6qt1/os-path-commonprefix-yes-that-old-chestnut))

```
foo = Path("C:\\route66\\foo")
baz = Path("C:\\route44\\baz")
baz.relative_to(os.path.commonprefix([baz,foo]))

> ...
> ValueError : `c:\\route44\baz` does not start with `C:\\route`
```

but rather the following one from [J. F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27885797).

```
Path(*os.path.commonprefix([foo.parts, baz.parts]))

> Path('c:/root')
```

... or if you're feeling verbose ...

```
from itertools import takewhile
Path(*[set(i).pop() for i in (takewhile(lambda x : x[0]==x[1], zip(foo.parts, baz.parts)))])
```

Answer (score 7):

This was bugging me, so here's a pathlib-only version that I think does what `os.path.relpath` does.

```
def relpath(path_to, path_from):
    path_to = Path(path_to).resolve()
    path_from = Path(path_from).resolve()
    try:
        for p in (*reversed(path_from.parents), path_from):
            head, tail = p, path_to.relative_to(p)
    except ValueError:  # Stop when the paths diverge.
        pass
    return Path('../' * (len(path_from.parents) - len(head.parents))).joinpath(tail)
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, this will lead to a different result if any of the paths is a symlink.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.12 added the `walk_up` parameter to the [`Path.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to) method. Now you can do:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> foo = Path.home() / 'foo'
>>> bar = Path.home() / 'bar'

>>> bar.relative_to(foo, walk_up=True)
PosixPath('../bar')
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive version of [@Brett_Ryland's relpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60671745/6662425) for pathlib. I find this to be a tad more readable and it is going to succeed on first `try` in most cases so it should have similar performance as the original `relative_to` function:

```py
def relative(target: Path, origin: Path):
    """ return path of target relative to origin """
    try:
        return Path(target).resolve().relative_to(Path(origin).resolve())
    except ValueError as e: # target does not start with origin
        # recursion with origin (eventually origin is root so try will succeed)
        return Path('..').joinpath(relative(target, Path(origin).parent))
```

Comment: i like this, but just a heads up, this will give one too many levels of recursion, so for

- `/home/me/subpath_a/subpath_b/file.exe`
- `/home/me/subpath_c/subpath_d/file.exe`

you'll get `../../../file.exe` rather than `../../file.exe`

i did a really lazy fix of throwing this inside an inner function and then removing the last `..` before returning and it worked, but not pretty

Comment: uhm - I assumed that origin would be a directory. I.e. the directory from which you want the relative path to go to. So if you pass `origin=/home/me/subpath_c/subpath_d/file.exe`, then `file.exe` is treated as a directory. So from there you have to go 3 times back until you get to `me`, i.e. `../../../` instead of `../..`.  In other words `origin` is the directory where your program is running in not a file.